# Use of "were" (subjunctive)

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I'd like to know if the use of *were* is correct in the sentence below or if it should be replaced with *was*:

> As if X **were**n't hard enough already, companies now face the
>   challenge to deliver Y.

For your response, assume that X is hard enough already.

Edit:

I'm aware that several questions related to the subjunctive "were" have been asked on this site. But they don't help me.

To clarify, I'm asking if the subjunctive mood is appropriate here. If so, I'd like to use the subjunctive. I'm not asking if it is OK to not use the subjunctive. (I know that in current English language it is more or less acceptable to not use the subjunctive even when it is called for.)

If it helps, I think my difficulty has roots in the negative phrase "weren't". I haven't found this negative subjunctive construction addressed anywhere.

Comment: That's a good discussion, but not what I need. Please see my edit.

Comment: At first blush, both "weren't" and "wasn't" seem to be acceptable here. They would both be used for their modal remoteness meaning (er, what's sometimes called "subjunctive" use), to show the speaker's opinion that they doubt the statement "X isn't hard enough already" (the speaker's own opinion is that X is hard enough already). A past-tense verb form can often be used to show this modal remoteness; the irrealis "were" is usually only used for that purpose of showing modal remoteness (but don't confuse this "were" with the past-tense verb form "were").

Comment: Did you consider the distinction between [*realis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realis_mood) and [*irrealis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood) moods offered in Colin Fine's answer? @F.E. just remade the point!

Comment: @F.E.: And as if that ***isn't*** enough, you have to put up with people saying *another* tense is also idiomatically acceptable!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: the subjunctive is a mood or aspect, certainly.  I wouldn't call it a tense, though.

Comment: @scottb: To a first approximation, the "technical" meaning of the word  ***tense*** isn't much use in respect of English. We only really have two (past and "not-past"), and even they aren't consistently observed (in casual speech, many native speakers are quite happy to use "historical present"). But sticking to your point, I think most people would say my *as if that **isn't** enough* looks like a "present tense" usage. If you want *yet another* mood/tense, there's also subjunctive *as if that **be** not enough*. (Not exactly "common", but certainly "acceptable" to me at a pinch! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As if X weren't hard enough already, companies now face the challenge to deliver Y.*

This is correct. As Peter Shor points out in his comment, the **negative** is hypothetical in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To find the answer, we should ask why the subjunctive is used in the first place: most commonly to express **potentiality** or **hypothetical situations**. In your example, since X really is hard enough already, it would appear to be an **actuality**, but as @Peter Shor pointed out, the way it is phrased is hypothetical (the "As if" makes it so), so the subjunctive indeed should be used--"*As if X weren't hard enough already*..."

Comment: Isn't it that the ***negative*** situation is hypothetical? This is like saying *"If he weren't here, I would have to make the decision."* He is here, but the clause is hypothetical because the sentence is postulating that he isn't here, which is not true. So you can use the subjunctive. For the OP's question, X is hard enough, so the hypothetical is that X isn't hard enough.

Comment: You can certainly find places where the subjunctive has historically been used in similar situations. From Google books: *as if it were not hard enough in all conscience for people to be cooped up in bricks and mortar all the year, without having the slow-pointing finger of scorn proclaiming them cockneys whenever they venture forth for a breath of fresh air.*